# Google play games not signing in

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have compared from logcat all 3 client id values, package name, SHA1 and app_id... they're all correct and I am still getting an error that I could not sign in because maybe those values are incorrect or people haven't been added to my testing list, but I added 5 friends and they're all having trouble signing in with my app...

I've gone through troubleshooting and did not succeed. Is there anything I could be missing?

Thanks

This is my manifest, decoded from APK using apktool:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="com.badjano.Mole"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:configChanges="locale|mcc|mnc|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="locale|mcc|mnc|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="1234567890" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.google.example.games.pluginsupport.SignInHelperActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.google.example.games.pluginsupport.SelectOpponentsHelperActivity" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.google.example.games.pluginsupport.InvitationInboxHelperActivity" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
    </application>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x20000" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: please post Manifest and code.

Comment: Posted Manifests, the code is just a call to authenticate user

Comment: Is that your file? maybe make sure that your second half is actually going between the manifest takes of the first part and not just adding more.

Comment: I just decompiled my APK to make sure everything is there, I updated the description!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just got the best answer out there, if you're having the same problem as I did, do the following:

Go to Google Developers Console ( where you put your credential ), enter your project, Billings and Settings and delete it, then go to Google Play Developer Console and you'll see that the game you created on "Game Services" has been removed, now this is where your mistake happened, when I created my game service and linked it to my game, I didn't pay attention to the finger print I was entering, but that has to be the final SHA1 that you will use, so do it carefully because you will have problems changing it afterwards.
After you've done all the process of linking your app, you will now have to go back to Google Developers Console and add a new client id ( don't delete the one that is there ) with your SHA1 from the DEBUG.keystore ( default keystore ), to get that just put this on your terminal "keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android" without the quotes.

I don't know why I had to delete my game service nor why I had to put the debug.keystore values on a new client id, but it works!

All this information can be found from several places, but I think by gathering all of this here would help someonelse!

PS: If you have changed your keystore from the last APK you uploaded, try to recover it, because I lost it and now I'll have to create another application, and therefore another game service for it with the new SHA1 :( because google won't accept uploads with different SHA1 for the same app...